# using getaddrinfo() only checks nscd cache first time if DNS times out

Tags: c, linux, getaddrinfo, nss

If I get an initial "Name or service not known" (EAI_NONAME), the next call to getaddrinfo() seems to go straight to the dns instead of checking the cache first (nscd logs show no lookup attempts, tcpdump shows traffic to DNS server). If the first call succeeds in getting an address, from then on, all getaddrinfo() calls go to nscd first, as expected.

I'm compiling against glibc-2.13 for arm linux. In my rc.d, nscd is started before my daemon. nscd is set to disallow shared caches, and maintain a host cache. I am using the nscd from busybox (0.47). nsswitch.conf is set so host checks cache/files/dns. hosts.conf is set to check files/bind.

My daemon is calling getaddrinfo().

I have debug logs for nscd running, and they show that the client started to read the DNS response closes with a "Broken Pipe" error.

After that it will show GAI attempts from other daemons attempting to use the cache (so I know it's not nscd locked up or anything), but the daemon that got EAI_NONAME never again contacts nscd to do a cache lookup.

If I restart the daemon, I get the same behaviour, *if* the first DNS query times out again.

Is there something in glibc that is invalidating my daemon's link to the cache? Is there a way to reconnect my daemon to the cache without restarting it (similar to forcing a resolv.conf re-load via res_init())?

Comment: "*... is there a way to reconnect my daemon to the cache without restarting it ...*" did you try to make your daemon call `getaddrinfo()` "**really**" often. Let's say 100++ times? Try it and monitor access to `nscd`. I can not test this here, but there might be a chance your daemon decides to test the `nscd` connection then again and if succesful uses it from then on.

Comment: "*If I restart the daemon, I get the same behaviour ...*" you are referring to your own daemon here, not to `nscd`, do you?

Comment: Btw: I get the idea mentioned above from inspecting eglibc's sources.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>As [alk mentions in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk), retrying `getaddrinfo()` more than 100 times should force a nscd query.</sub>

---

To understand why, let us take a quick peek into the flow of execution *inside* **getaddrinfo()**.

1. [`getaddrinfo()` calls gaih_inet](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c?v=GLIBC27#L1917).
2. [**`gaih_inet()`**](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c?v=GLIBC27#L591)
   performs the following operations on `__nss_not_use_nscd_hosts` :

   - Checks whether it is a positive integer?
   - Increments it.
   - Checks whether it exceeds the retry count [**`NSS_NSCD_RETRY`**](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nscd/nscd_proto.h?v=GLIBC27#L28)?

     - It attempts to query nscd ONLY if both the above conditions are satisfied.
     - Also upon attempting a query to nscd, the count is immediately reset to zero
       thereby ignoring nscd for the next [**`NSS_NSCD_RETRY`**](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nscd/nscd_proto.h?v=GLIBC27#L28) times `getaddrinfo()` is called.
3. Also [**`__nss_not_use_nscd_hosts`**](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c?v=GLIBC27#L1917) is modified internally by nscd in the following places

   - [nscd/nscd_gethst_r.c](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nscd/nscd_gethst_r.c?v=GLIBC27) lines 178, 189
     -- reset to `1`.
   - [nscd/nscd_getai.c](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nscd/nscd_getai.c?v=GLIBC27) lines 89, 164
     -- reset to `1`.
   - [nss/nsswitch.c, line 709](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/nss/nsswitch.c?v=GLIBC27#L704)
     -- set to `-1` i.e. Disable nscd.

> Based on the above, it can be concluded that
>   `getaddrinfo()` does NOT query nscd every single time.

The internal state of nscd (determined by `__nss_not_use_nscd_hosts`)
decides if `getaddrinfo()` ends up calling nscd or not.

> To really force one's way around the 100 retry limitation, one could modify
>   `NSS_NSCD_RETRY` and rebuild libc to deviate from the standard
>   behaviour. But i am not really sure if this will NOT result in any
>   other unintended regressions.

Reference : [**Patch**](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-hacker/2004-09/txt00003.txt) that introduced the `__nss_not_use_nscd_hosts` logic in `getaddrinfo()`.